# Solve $y''-y'-2y=0$ using the power series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

First of all, by solving this the normal way, the answer should be:

$y=Ae^{2x}+Be^{-x}$

What I have so far:

$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }a_nx^n$

$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }na_nx^{n-1}$

$y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty }(n-1)(n)a_nx^{n-2}$

Shifting the counter to make it all $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }$

$y'=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}$

$y''=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}x^{n}$

Therefore, I get:

$(n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}-(n+1)a_{n+1}-2a_n=0$

From this, my recursion formula is:

$a_{n+2}=\frac{2a_n+(n+1)a_{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

I then evaluated this from $n=0$ to $n=6$ but my $a_2$ to $a_8$ values seem to be all over the place.

$a_2 = \frac{2a_0+a_{1}}{2!}$

$a_3 = \frac{2a_0+3a_{1}}{3!}$

$a_4 = \frac{6a_0+5a_{1}}{4!}$

$a_5 = \frac{10a_0+11a_{1}}{5!}$

$a_6 = \frac{22a_0+21a_{1}}{6!}$

$a_7 = \frac{42a_0+43a_{1}}{7!}$

$a_8 = \frac{86a_0+85a_{1}}{8!}$

I researched a bit and found out that the coefficients of $a_1$ follow the Jacobsthal sequence while the coefficients of $a_0$ are twice the Jacobsthal sequence but I think this is wrong as it is nowhere near the power series expansion of $y=Ae^{2x}+Be^{-x}$

Comment: I think you should keep things separated. You can try to solve your recurrence relation with $\mathcal{Z}$-transform, or show by induction that $a_n = \frac{1}{n!} (A 2^n + B(-1)^n)$ for some $A$ and $B.$

Comment: I think you are differentiating and shifting the index at the same time (first two steps), which I believe is wrong. You should end up with two sets of $a_i$'s that lead you to the two independent solution. You don't see these because you have incorrectly calculated $y'$ and $y''$

Answer (score 3):

Multiply your recursion equation with $n!$ and set $b_n=n!a_n$ to get the difference equation with constant coefficients
$$
b_{n+2}-b_{n+1}-2b_n=0.
$$
Now its characteristic equation will be the same as the one for the DE, so
$$
b_n=c_1(-1)^n+c_22^n
$$
from where you can recover the exponential basis solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry for the dumb question but I can't seem to understand how


$b_{n+2}-b_{n+1}-2b_n=0$


 turn into


$b_n=c_1(-1)^n+c_{2}2^n$


 and how does this turn into the final answer which is


$y=a_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{2^nx^n}{n!}+a_1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Comment: You get the characteristic equation for difference equations $0=q^2-q-2=(q+1)(q-2)$ and form linear combinations of the basis solutions $(-1)^n$ and $2^n$ as general solution. This works without further concerns as all roots are simple.

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't know that you can create a characteristic equation out of that. I'm only familiar with characteristic equations when they're used in solving ODEs so the concept of using it in a linear recurrence is pretty interesting. Thanks again!